# How to externalize a class that extends another

Tags: java

**Introduction**

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo extends ArrayList<ElementsClass> implements Externalizable {
    Field field1 = new Field();
    Field field2 = new Field();

    ...
}
```

I implement the methods `writeExternal` and `readExternal` like this:

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {        
    out.writeObject(field1);
    out.writeObject(field2);
}

public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    field1 = (Field) in.readObject();
    field2 = (Field) in.readObject();
}
```

**Observation**

One of the fields is not `Serializable` that is why I implement `Externalizable`. I want to externalize only those things that I am able to.

**Problem**

Although I know that the `ArrayList<ElementsClass>` is serializable if `ElementsClass` is serializable, I don't know how to externalize the class `Foo` itself.

Comment: What class `Class` do you mean? `java.lang.Class` or your own? This is bad practice to name custom classes with standard names.

Comment: Sorry, I used a ambiguous name, I meant a `Foo` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {        
    out.writeObject(super.toArray());
    out.writeObject(field1);
    out.writeObject(field2);
}

public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    Object[] arr = (Object[]) in.readObject();
    for (int k=0; k<arr.length; k++) super.add(arr[k]);
    field1 = (Field) in.readObject();
    field2 = (Field) in.readObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not that your class `Foo` is already externalized?

If you execute, statements like below, It should write the object in the file with the entries of externalized attributes.

```
    Foo class = new Foo();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp");
    ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(class );
```

Comment: Your code would throw a `NotSerializable` Exception because my `Foo` class contains a Field that is not serializable. That's why I implement Externalizable.

Comment: This is why you are using `Externalizable` in place of `Serializable`. In `writeExternal`, directly write the fields, which are `serializable`. For `non-searializable` fields, get the internal attributes manually and then write them. You need to the `reverse` of the same in `readExternal` method.

Comment: I don't need to Externalize the fields that are not Serializable. I just skip them. The problem is that I need to externalize the class itself and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Kits89 You have already accepted the answer which is very similar to what I mentioned here. Not sure, what else are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try a custom serialization, like the one descriped here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290812/1548788