# How to save a non-serializable attribute of an object with Android?

Tags: android

I have had an error for a while now that I just found out was causing it. I have an ArrayList, as for each object that I want saved, I am wanting a list of pending intents used for the AlarmManager, that way if I want to delete the multiple alarms from each object, all I have to do is access the list of PendingIntents and simply use alarmmanagername.cancel(PendingIntent) across the arraylist for it. But these object need to be store, and upon retrieval of the stored objects, the arraylist is set to null as I had to set it to transient to have the object data store and be retrieved into the system without throwing a NotSerializableException. Here is how the class is set up:

```
public class ListObject implements Serializable{

    public String objectname, startampm, stopampm;  //name of schedule and am or pm
    private boolean[] Days = {
            false,  //monday
            false,  //tuesday
            false,  //and soforth
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false};

    private int starthour, startminute, stophour, stopminute;   //times from TimePicker
    public transient ArrayList<PendingIntent> pendintentlist = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();; //ids for each of the alarms
    private int listalarmid;    //FOR WHEN COME BACK: maybe store pending intents instead of the array of ints above?
    private boolean vibrate, activated;
    private boolean nextday = false; //bool for if schedule goes into next day
```

From what I understand, transient makes it to where it cannot be saved with the rest of the data however, how can I go about saving this non-serializable object with the rest of the data, so that when it is retrieved, I can access this arraylist without it turning null?

If not, is there an easier way of being able to later cancel alarmmanagers that I am wanting to save? It is a simple app that lets you save multiple alarms, I just need a way of saving their pending intents.

Answer (score 0):

It is either designed to be saved with the rest of the state or it is not, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the transient data.

- A `PendingIntend` is still `Parceable` so you can write it to a `Bundle`, for example if using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`
- Transient data may be 'figured', that is the state is not saved directly but you can save the data required to recreate it if require. eg a database connection is not serialisable, but you may be able to store the username, password and JDBC URL.
- you can override (or implement) the java Serialization methods `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)` and `readObject(ObjectInputStream in)` and add your transient field eg [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290812/530513)