# serialisation of SimpleStringProperty in java

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to serialize objects of SimpleStringProperty but the following exception is popping up.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:793)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
at roomBookingSystem.Project1.main(Project1.java:1392)
```

Comment: JavaFX properties are not serializable, because it is not clear how the state of listeners should be serialized, or even if it can be serialized. You will have to write your own serialization logic.

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791566/notserializableexception-on-simplelistproperty