# How to serialize SimpleIntegerProperty?

Tags: java, javafx

I have class `RowReader` containing couple of `SimpleIntegerProperty`.

I would like to save state of objects. Serialization would be great, but `SimpleIntegerProperty` is not serializable.

`RowReader` has only integer attributes so I can create new class having list attributes and serialize it. After deserialization I can create `RowReader` object and initialize it using integer values from list.

This looks like a lot of work and doesn't look nice (it's not only 1 class to save that way). Is there other way?

My question is: How should I save `SimpleIntegerProperty` values to file?

Comment: It's unclear what you asking, could you provide a minimal example ?

Comment: What's the problem with just writing out the values of the integer properties.

Comment: You need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791566/notserializableexception-on-simplelistproperty see answer from Elloco