# Java Serialization for a non-serializable attribute

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class that needs to be serialized.

Example

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
   Column column;
   public Column getColumn() {
       return column;
   }
}
```

When I try to serialize the employee object, I get the exception

java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.Column
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)

I cannot make Column attribute as transient, because information is required.
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Implement [custom serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7290812/2071828) or use some other method to persist the your object. N.B. Please stick to Java naming conventions, classes should be in `PascalCase`; so `Employee`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot make Column attribute as transient". You should make it `Serializable` as well, if that's an option.

Comment: If you have Column class then make it serializable too.

Comment: @Deepak2221 : Column Class is present in some API, I cannot change

Comment: @Drux, I don't want to make it transient. I want the information after de-serialization. How do I make it Serializable, that was my question?

Comment: Related: [transient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables). IMO you should mention in your question that you cannot change `Column` (as stated in a comment below).

Answer (score 2):

to implement custom serialization you must implement writeObject and readObject in Employee as below:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) {
    // throws IOException {
   try {
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeInt( ... ); // here serialize column
   } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) {
    // throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   try {
    is.defaultReadObject();
    column = new Column( /*is.readInt() ... */); // here deserialize column
   } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

also you should mark your column field, that is of non Serializable type as transient:

```
transient Column column;
```

this way ObjectOutputStream will skip serializing it (no exception will be thrown), and you will serialize it in readObject.

Answer (score 0):

Column class should be implementing Serializable

Comment: Column Class is present in some API, I cannot change

Answer (score 0):

If you need the information after unserialization, you must use [custom serialization](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2097430/java-se/serializing-java-objects-with-non-serializable-attributes.html).

Comment: This too looks like a good one. Let me try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution of this. Make a custom class by extending Column and implement and make it Serializable.

```
class ColumnDup extends Column implements Serializable{}
```

and use ColumnDup in place of Column.

Comment: @PalaniappanMeiyappan this might be your solution.

Comment: this will not work, Column fields will be default initialized after deserialization

Comment: @marcin_j can you explain this in deep.

Comment: This is because during deserialization of non-Serializable base classes, their constructors will get executed causing default initialization. Inside ObjectStreamClass.newInstance() you can read: `Creates a new instance of the represented class. If the class is externalizable, invokes its public no-arg constructor; otherwise, if the class is serializable, **invokes the no-arg constructor of the first non-serializable superclass.**`

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom serialization bu using

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)

refer this useful link http://www.coderanch.com/t/504517/java/java/Customize-readObject-writeObject