# How to store object implementing org.apache.geode.pdx.PdxSerializable in file in java

Tags: java, java-8, nio, geode

I have a class implementing `org.apache.geode.pdx.PdxSerializable` and need to store the objects of it in a file in java. For storing in files, the object needs to be `Serializable` but the class PDXSerializable is being used for storing data in gemfire and then hence we cannot use Serializable class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use custom object serialization?. Here's an example that I have quickly created;

```
 private class Foo implements PdxSerializable {
        private String bar;
        private Integer baz;

        public Foo(final String bar, final Integer baz) {

            this.bar = bar;
            this.baz = baz;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return bar;
        }

        public Integer getBaz() {
            return baz;
        }
        public void toData(PdxWriter out) {
         //your pdx stuff
        }

        public void fromData(PdxReader in) {
          //your pdx work
        }
    }

//and a custom reader and writer 
     private void writeCustom(final Foo foo, final Path path) throws IOException {
        try(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path.toFile()))) {
            objectOutputStream.writeChars(foo.getBar());
            objectOutputStream.writeInt(foo.getBaz());
        }
    }

    private Foo readCustom(final Path path) throws IOException {
        try(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))) {
            String bar = objectInputStream.readUTF();
            Integer baz = objectInputStream.readInt();
            return new Foo(bar, baz);
        }
    }
```

Custom Serialization Oracle docs - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

A similar question with great answers -  [Java Custom Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at JSONFormatter:

http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/pdx/JSONFormatter.html

It has a static method that turns a PDXInstance into a JSON String.

Assuming the data is in GemFire then getting it out as a PDXInstance just requires you to write a simple client with "pdx-read-serialized" set to true.  With that setting, when your client calls get or getAll the objects returned will be PDXInstances and you can use JSONFormatter to turn them into JSON directly.