# JavaFX Serialization Error With ObservableListWrapper

Tags: javafx, arraylist, serialization, observablelist

I am creating a program that needs to save an ObservableList and a Theme (which is a variable) in different archives, but my code doesn't work, I tried to convert my ObservableList into an ArrayList (which is Serializable) but it still throws an error. The error is this:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper
```

And my code is this for serialization:

```
            try{
                File file1 = new File("c:/FmsTimer/saveFmsTimer.fmstiming");
                FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fos1);
                oos1.writeObject(new ArrayList<session>(listS));
                oos1.close();
                fos1.close();

                File file2 = new File("c:/FmsTimer/cfg.fmstiming");
                FileOutputStream fos2= new FileOutputStream(file2);
                ObjectOutputStream oos2= new ObjectOutputStream(fos2);
                oos2.writeObject(myTheme.name());
                oos2.close();
                fos2.close();

                System.exit(1);
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is for reading when the program starts:

```
   try {
        File file1 = new File("c:/FmsTimer/saveFmsTimer.fmstiming");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        ArrayList arraylistTemp = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
        listS = FXCollections.observableList(arraylistTemp);

        File file2 = new File("c:/FmsTimer/cfg.fmstiming");
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
        ObjectInputStream ois2 = new ObjectInputStream(fis2);

        String t;
        t = (String) ois2.readObject();
        ois2.close();
        fis2.close();
        myTheme = Themes.valueOf(t);


    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        //return;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
        System.out.println("Class not found");
        c.printStackTrace();
        // return;
    }
```

My **"listS"** is an ObservableList and **"myTheme"** is an instance of an Enum, **"session"** is an Class (which is Serializable by the way).

Thanks and if you need more information just let me know. (PS: sorry if I made some english mistakes, it's not my main language)

**--UPDATE--** This is the stack trace of the error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at program.mainClass.lambda$start$2(mainClass.java:183)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: As requested by kleopatra, you need to _create_ a [mre] demonstrating the problem and then add it to your question via an [edit]. The example should include the class you're attempting to serialize, as well as any non-standard classes said class depends on (i.e. the field types)—keeping in mind the example should be _minimal_. Also, the error you give is related to how no core `ObservableList` implementations are `Serializable` but you also mention you get an error when you've copied the elements over to an `ArrayList`; show us the stack trace of that error, please.

Comment: @Slaw I updated the question, the stack trace of the error is there now, hope this is what you're looking for. :D and I'll create the minimal reproducible example as soon as I can.

Comment: @Slaw, so Session starts like this:
`public class session implements Runnable, Serializable `
and it has a ObservableList<solve>, Solve is like that:
`public class solve implements Serializable`
the only piece of code that uses serialization is in my question. 
I think that the ObservableList inside the session class is the problem, if it is, how can I solve it without having to replace it (it is used in a ListView so, it needs to exist), thank you :D

Comment: You can [customize the serialization process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization) (see the linked/related questions as well).