# How to fix sonar Serializable issue?

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a code snippet where I getting critical code smell from sonar because exception implements serializable. This code work fine in production for a long time and I can't see any issues from Sonar doc: "For instance, under load, most J2EE application frameworks flush objects to disk, and an allegedly Serializable object with non-transient, non-serializable data members could cause program crashes". Do you face with code crashes in your application with this sonar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to de/serialize the `entries` field use the [`transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3) keyword:

```
private final transient List<Objects> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

Otherwise, you have to implement a [custom de/serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization), however, I am not sure it would resolve the Sonar issue. The keyword `transient` does resolve the Sonar issue.

> J2EE application frameworks flush objects to disk

It depends whether the object `OuterException` itself is actually de/serialized. I doubt J2EE serializes custom objects made by yourself without being told to do so. Actually, feel free to close the issue with the "*Won't Fix*" resolution and an appropriate comment, which is no wrong.